# Diffrence between Buon and Buono

Tags: grammar, difference

What is the difference between *buon* and *buono*? Are there any rules to use them? I know they are masculine because *buon'* and *buona* are feminine.

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen buon' (with an apostrophe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Buono](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buono1/):

> - **si tronca in buon** davanti a **vocale e davanti a consonante seguita da vocale o da l o da r**.

Esempi:

- Buon Anno
- buon pasto
- buon lavoro
- buon ritorno